# Why am I getting different results from the same python code for the same input data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote some code for a cp contest and I have this piece of code:

```
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    solve()
```

I got 2 different outputs for the same data when a) it is the only input and b) when it was the final input out of the 3 test cases. The same .py file gives different outputs for the same input and I'm completely lost. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance :D

The question was:

You are given a tree with N nodes. The i-th node has value a[i]. Recall that a tree is a connected graph with N-1 edges. When you remove any one edge from a tree, you get two trees.
Let f(T) be a function that takes input a tree T and returns the maximum value among all nodes in that tree. More formally, if the i-th node has value b[i] then f(T) = max({b[1], b[2], ..., b[k-1], b[k]}) where k is the number of nodes in the tree.
Let us take a random edge that exists in the tree and remove it. Let us call the two trees formed as T1 and T2.
Find the expected value of |f(T1) - f(T2)| modulo 10^9 + 7. Note that each edge has equal probability of being selected.

The code:

```
from math import gcd

MOD=(10**9+7)

def inv(a,m):
    m0=m
    y=0
    x=1
    if m==1:
        return 0
    while a>1:
        q=a//m
        t=m
        m=a%m
        a=t
        t=y
        y=x-q*y
        x=t
    if x<0:
        x=x+m0
    return x

def dfs_update_max(graph,source,values,visited=[]):
    if source not in visited:
        visited.append(source)
        if not graph[source]:
            return
        for neighbour in graph[source]:
            if(neighbour not in visited):
                print(f"edge {source}--{neighbour}")
                dfs_update_max(graph,neighbour,values,visited)
                values[source-1]=max(values[neighbour-1],values[source-1])
                print(f"back {neighbour}--{source} value at {source} updated as max of node values at {neighbour} and {source}={values[source-1]}")
        print(values)

def solve():
    n=int(input())
    g={}
    e=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        g[i]=[]
    for i in range(n-1):
        u,v=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
        g[u].append(v)
        g[v].append(u)
        e.append([u-1,v-1])
    values=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
    max=values[0]
    max_index=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(values[i]>max):
            max=values[i]
            max_index=i
    dfs_update_max(g,max_index+1,values)
    num=0
    for i,j in e:
        num+=values[max_index]-min(values[i],values[j])
    den=n-1
    print(values, "outside")
    x=gcd(num,den)
    p=num//x
    q=den//x
    q_=inv(q,MOD)
    print(p*q_%MOD)

t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    solve()
```

Input format:

First line contains an integer T denoting number of test cases. Then T test cases follow.
First line of each test case contains a single integer N denoting number of nodes in the tree.
Next N-1 lines contains 2 integers each u,v describing an edge between node u and v. It is guaranteed that these edges form a tree.
The next line contains N integers a[1], a[2], ..., a[N]

file 1:

```
3
3
1 2
1 3
1 5 5
3
1 2
1 3
5 1 5
10
4 6
4 1
4 7
6 5
7 9
5 8
9 3
1 2
7 10
15 23 90 4 29 44 105 30 27 81
```

file 2:

```
1
10
4 6
4 1
4 7
6 5
7 9
5 8
9 3
1 2
7 10
15 23 90 4 29 44 105 30 27 81
```

Comment: Just a heads up that visited=[] is only evaluated once in class context.  This means that the value is shared if you instance the class multiple times, i.e. use None as the default and then in method do: visited = visited or [].

Comment: @AllanWind that actually worked. Thanks a lot!! Now only thing that is hanging is that I never used class here. So, ```visited=[]``` must actually work fine right? I don't get whats happening.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really an issue here as you use that in a function, opposed to (class) method.  It was must a heads-up.

Comment: I haven't spent much time reviewing your code as it's too much work (i.e. minimize the issue, hard-code input instead of an interactive program, multiple files etc).  What stood out to me was you said the data was the same, then I look at file 1 and 2 and they are not.  You speak of probability and this means determinism goes out the window.

Comment: By "same" I meant, the arguments to the solve() function will be same when it is called the 3rd time in the 1st input and for the second input. But I never imagined visited=[] takes place only once. That must not be the case ideally.. Thanks for your time! I appreciate that :D